# Use R to subset multiple data frames based on the same condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, lapply

I am working with multiple data frames named dm6, mm10 and hg38. They look like this:

```
head(dm6)
    chr  txStart    txEnd strand geneName  refGeneName geneLength
1 chr3L 19751440 19793319      -  CG42637 NM_001007095      41877
2 chr2L   870714   876537      +    PNUTS NM_001014453       5824
3 chr2L   871344   873648      +    PNUTS NM_001014454       2305
4 chr2L   870714   873648      +    PNUTS NM_001014455       2935
5 chr2L  1792557  1793018      -    Gr22b NM_001014456        462
6 chr2L  1997602  2006063      -  CG33543 NM_001014458       8462
    gbRPK_NHS  gbRPK_HS20 FC_HS20_vs_NHS log2FC_HS20_vs_NHS
1  685.348600  282.196300      0.4117558         -1.2801390
2 4466.123000  838.157600      0.1876701         -2.4137290
3 6268.892000 1036.923000      0.1654077         -2.5959010
4 6723.241000 1176.968000      0.1750596         -2.5140820
5    4.329004    2.164502      0.5000000         -1.0000000
6   12.455380   14.105770      1.1325050          0.1795171
  dRPK_HS20_vs_NHS Regulation pVal_DESeq2_HS20_vs_NHS
1      -403.152400     DownHC            4.247334e-02
2     -3627.965000     DownHC            5.838478e-05
3     -5231.969000     DownHC            1.866207e-05
4     -5546.273000     DownHC            2.595508e-05
5        -2.164502      UnReg            7.866483e-01
6         1.650396      UnReg            9.002195e-01
```

I would like to make subsets like this, in which I would have a subset with all rows that have UpHC in the column Regulation:

```
dm_up=subset(dm6, Regulation=="UpHC")
mm_up=subset(mm10, Regulation=="UpHC")
hg_up=subset(hg38, Regulation=="UpHC")
```

Is there a way to do this all at once?

I tried to put my data frames in a list:

```
df <- c("dm6"=dm6, "mm10"=mm10, "hg38"=hg38)
```

And then use lapply, but It does not give the expected result:

```
df_up <- lapply(df, subset, df[grepl("Regulation", names(df))] == "UpHC")
```

Result:

```
$dm6.chr
character(0)

$dm6.txStart
numeric(0)

$dm6.txEnd
integer(0)

$dm6.strand
character(0)

$dm6.geneName
character(0)

$dm6.refGeneName
character(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Use a `list`, not `c`, as in `df <- list("dm6"=dm6, "mm10"=mm10, "hg38"=hg38)`, so that each element is its own perfect frame (the use of `c` returns a single list of vectors.

   ```r
   ### wrong
   quux <- c(mtcars[1:3,1:3], mtcars[1:4,1:3])
   str(quux)
   # List of 6
   #  $ mpg : num [1:3] 21 21 22.8
   #  $ cyl : num [1:3] 6 6 4
   #  $ disp: num [1:3] 160 160 108
   #  $ mpg : num [1:4] 21 21 22.8 21.4
   #  $ cyl : num [1:4] 6 6 4 6
   #  $ disp: num [1:4] 160 160 108 258

   ### correct
   quux <- list(mtcars[1:3,1:3], mtcars[1:4,1:3])
   str(quux)
   # List of 2
   #  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
   #   ..$ mpg : num [1:3] 21 21 22.8
   #   ..$ cyl : num [1:3] 6 6 4
   #   ..$ disp: num [1:3] 160 160 108
   #  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
   #   ..$ mpg : num [1:4] 21 21 22.8 21.4
   #   ..$ cyl : num [1:4] 6 6 4 6
   #   ..$ disp: num [1:4] 160 160 108 258
   ```
2. From there, `lapply(df, subset, subset = Regulation=="UpHC")`.

   ```r
   lapply(quux, subset, subset = cyl == 4)
   # [[1]]
   #             mpg cyl disp
   # Datsun 710 22.8   4  108
   # [[2]]
   #             mpg cyl disp
   # Datsun 710 22.8   4  108
   ```